# React Native : iterate and display nested objects using Hooks

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-native-flatlist

I want to display my user data stored in my api's 
How can I iterate through my apis data.
Can anyone demonstrate it with example ?
My api data looks like this:

```
{
  "data": {
    "__v": 0,
    "_id": "5edaa8cc76d6b20017",
    "createdAt": "2020-06-05T20:19:24.365Z",
    "email": "joe@gmail.com",
    "name": "Joe",
    "role": "user"
  },
  "success": true
}
```

Here is the example of my code:

```
const HomeScreen = props => {

  const [dataSource, setDatasource] = useState({});

  const Boiler = async () => {
    const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');
    fetch('{{URL}}/api/v1/auth/me', {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: new Headers({
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token,
      }),
    })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(responeJson => {

        console.log(responeJson);
        setDatasource({
          ...dataSource,
          dataSource: responeJson,
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    Boiler();
  }, []);

}
```

Comment: I would suggest you add some screen shot or mockup, which shows what do you want to achieve by iterating.
Answer by Shubham below https://stackoverflow.com/a/62255337/5332817
should work if your response has fixed structure (keys) so you can just bind to ui.

If you have variable keys then answer by roman https://stackoverflow.com/a/62255338/5332817 can be used and there you can bind the data as per need.

Answer (score 2):

You response from the API is an object which you can directly render in your component without the need for iteration

Also note that when you update state, you would not explicitly set key as `dataSource`

Update your state like

```
   setDatasource({
      ...dataSource,
      ...responeJson.data,
   });
```

and then render your data like

```
return (
   <View>
       <Text>CreatedAt: {dataSource.createdAt}</Text>
       <Text>email: {dataSource.email}</Text>
       <Text>name: {dataSource.name}</Text>
       <Text>role: {dataSource.role}</Text>
   </View>

)
```

Comment: I want to access the data i.e (value) from the objects and display it on my screen. I tried your solution but the data is not rendered on the screen.

Comment: Did you also update it the way I showed? `setDatasource({
      ...dataSource,
      ...responeJson.data,
   });`

Comment: It worked thanks, I forgot to add data after ...responeJson.data. Thankyou for your solution. :)

Comment: Glad to have helped.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to iterate over object use can use `for..in` loop.

```js
const response = {
  "data": {
    "__v": 0,
    "_id": "5edaa8cc76d6b20017",
    "createdAt": "2020-06-05T20:19:24.365Z",
    "email": "joe@gmail.com",
    "name": "Joe",
    "role": "user"
  },
  "success": true
};

function iterateOverData(data) {
  for(let key in data) {
    console.log(key, data[key]);
  }
}

iterateOverData(response.data);
```